# Xcode Textfield in Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

im new to swift and I got a problem. I wanted to create a keyboard with integrated textfield but I can't find any good solution for this. My code is working halfway but its pretty bad code and it throws a warning everytime I click the done button. I would appreciate any kind of suggestions.

This is my first post and I hope anyone can help me here...

My Code:

````
class AddPlayersViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let test: UIButton = {
        let test = UIButton()
        return test
    }()
    
    
    let field: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "Enter Player Name"
        field.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return field
    
    }()

    
    let field2: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "Enter Name"
        field.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return field
    
    }()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        view.addSubview(field2)
        
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
        
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target:self, action: #selector(didTapDone))
        
        

        let textField = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: field)
    
        
        
        toolBar.items = [textField, flexibleSpace, doneButton]
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        field2.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @objc private func didTapDone() {

        field2.resignFirstResponder()
        
        let text: String? = field.text
        print(text!)
        field.resignFirstResponder()

    }

  
    
    
    @IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "party_one") as! PartyOneViewController

        
        field2.becomeFirstResponder()
        field.becomeFirstResponder()


        
    
    


}``` 

Warning:
2022-03-19 00:18:34.462786+0100 Test[11700:942120] [View] First responder warning: '<UITextField: 0x103e043f0; frame = (0 0; 140.333 22); text = 'Ghhhhh'; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x28094af10>; placeholder = Enter Player Name; borderStyle = None; background = <_UITextFieldNoBackgroundProvider: 0x2805c0320: textfield=<UITextField 0x103e043f0>>; layer = <CALayer: 0x2807f8ac0>>' rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy
2022-03-19 00:18:39.947928+0100 Test[11700:942120] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x107809800, UIKeyboardImpl) that is not in a visible window requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
````

Answer (score 0):

on my side problem appear with ios 15.4 and disappear with 15.4.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).